# Accountability on judgement day regarding Salah after turning back to Allah swt

Tags: salat, day-of-judgement

The first question Allah swt will ask his slave is about Salah if it's complete then he is saved if it's incomplete then he is doomed - What is the fate of the one having been born into a muslim family but has not been practicing but has repented and only recently turned back to his lord having missed many years of salah and was to die in that state?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Aleikum

No one knows their position with Allah in terms of what good deeds have been accepted.
A Muslim is between two states: Hope and fear.

Allah alone knows the knowledge of the unseen. Our goal is to strive and exert our best efforts to get closer to Allah by following the Quran and the Sunnah of the Prophet Muhammad (SAW).

Remember to always include all Muslims in your prayers.

Allaahuma Aqfiril Muminiina Wal Muminaat
Wal Muslimiina Wal Muslimaat
Al Ahyaa Un Wal Amwat
Birahmatika Yaa Arhama Raahimiin.

Answer (score 0):

Allah pardons, forgives the sins of the one who repents.

Allah says: Indeed, I am the Perpetual Forgiver of whoever repents and believes and does righteousness and then continues in guidance. Surah Ta-Ha (20:82).

[Read more.](https://understandquran.com/what-is-tawbah-why-should-we-repent-to-allah/)

However, don't forget those who are like what you were. Never stop advising and trying to get them repent